# How to submit the same form multiple times on same page and also process them on that page in php

Tags: php

I am trying to display a form and process data on same page multiple times.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function display($q) {      
    $que=mysqli_fetch_row($q);
    $_SESSION['qid']=$que[0];
    ob_start ();    
?>  

<form method="post" action="">
    <h3> <?php echo $que[0]." . ".$que[2]; ?> </h3>
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<?php echo $que[3]; ?>"> <?php echo $que[3]; ?> <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<?php echo $que[4]; ?>"> <?php echo $que[4]; ?> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="next" >
</form>

<?php
    $_SESSION['qid']=$que[0];
    echo $_SESSION['qid'];
    if(isset($_POST['next'])) {
        if(array_key_exists('next',$_POST)){
            next_que();
        }
    }
}

function next_que() {
    //some code 
    // calling display function
}
?>
```

When I run this code, the `display` and `next_que` functions are working properly the first time, but on the next call only the `display` function is called displaying the form, and clicking the button doesn't turn the `isset($_POST['next'])` condition to true.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, prevent the form from submit via prevent default in your javascript. Then you can call your javascript functions / code on any button click and use the data in the same page.

Comment: but i am trying to call php functions.

Comment: Then you have to use ajax for that.

Comment: but i wanted to know whats wrong with my code. isset($_POST[]) method should be called on every button click but this is not happening here.

Comment: isset($_POST) only works at server side. You have to send data to the php script